# What is the thinking behind having foreach cast to the variable type?

Tags: c#

Seems like we could just have a normal statically checked assignment.  I'm not sure I see the advantage in this case.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Adi: Foreach works with the non-generic `IEnumerable`, and will add an implicit conversion.  I believe this is what Dejas is referring to here...

Comment: Meh... Use `var` - problem evaporates (you can't do anything except the correct/no-op assignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `foreach` was designed prior to generics, which didn't exist until .NET 2.0.  With .NET 1.1, if you used a collection class, the `IEnumerator` interface's [`Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx) property always returns `System.Object`.

By having foreach do the cast, you could write:

```
foreach(string item in collection)
```

Instead of having to explicitly write:

```
foreach(object temp in collection)
{
     string item = (string)temp;
```

Granted, with .NET 2, this is not really an issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The history of `foreach` predates generic `IEnumerable`  and so it facilitated enumerating over collections such as `ArrayList`.  Now that .NET has generic collections and `ArrayList` is rarely used, the free casting does seem like a bit of an impedance mismatch with the way it would have been designed if the feature were added now.

Nevertheless, now that we have the feature, you still see people use it even with generic collections to cast up to the type that they know they want, thereby avoiding a few lines of code.  This is not too far removed from how it was used in the `ArrayList` days.